# How to use Monitor in threading without exclusive lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C#/.Net application.

I use `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` to acquire exclusive access on some object to synchronize threads.

I have a specific case where a thread 1 should acquire exclusive access on some object. Another thread 2 should behave as follows : I there is no exclusive lock on the object, it should continue without acquiring exclusive lock. I there is already an exclusive lock acquired by another thread, It should wait until it's released.

I have been looking in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=net-5.0).

But I couldn't find any function that does this.

Is that possible please?

Comment: ReaderWriterLockSlim behaves like that I think.

Comment: Are you trying to implement some sort of thread-safe initialization?

Answer (score 2):

So:

- if the object is currently locked, you wish to wait for it to be released, but not take the lock
- if the object is not currently locked, you wish to continue without holding the lock

I believe that is achieved by simply:

```cs
lock (theThing) {}
```

This acquires and releases, which has the same semantics as not taking the lock, but waiting for anyone who does hold it.

Note that there is inherently a race condition in what you ask, as if you're not taking the lock: someone else could after you've checked. We long as that is OK.

There are also a myriad of methods on `Monitor` for other scenarios, usually mixed with `try`/`finally` - in particular, `TryEnter` with a zero timeout can be used for "take the lock immediately if you can, but don't wait if you can't".

However, a `ManualResetEvent` may also be worth investigating.